# How to update an SSDT project from the command line?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I hope to be able to use SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) to put our database schema under version control. Importing a database into an SSDT project in Visual Studio creates a nice textual representation of the database schema, suitable for versioning.

Now, the question is, when changes are made to the database schema - how can we programmatically, or from the command line, update (or re-import) the SSDT project?

Comment: I believe you do not want to use the schema compare as an option

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in schema compare tool to do this, but it seems that you are not developing the way SSDT database projects want you to. It's designed for offline editing, which means you need to first edit the .sql files in your project, and use F5 to deploy to your dev DB for testing.

If you'd prefer to keep working connected, you might want to try [SQL Change Automation](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/readyroll/), a tool we offer here at Redgate. This has a one-click import option that automates the pulling down of database changes to your database project.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I wonder if there is any way to automate the built-in schema compare tool...

Comment: sqlpackage.exe is the command line, but according to the docs it doesn't appear to allow you to set the project as the target.