# Updating a Visual Studio SQL Server Database project from a database using command line

Tags: visual-studio, continuous-integration, sql-server-data-tools

Can the Schema Comparison tools in SSDT be used from the command line to update a Visual Studio database project?

In my environment, I have a mix of developers using different tools to manage database objects in our SQL databases. Some are using Visual Studio and SSDT, some are using Red Gate tools, and some are using notepad. I'd like to use our CI server to sync changes into the VS project that have gotten into the database through other means.

Comment: I don't know that I'd be comfortable automatically pulling in all changes from one server into the project. However, it's not supported in an automated fashion at this time per this blog post - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2016/09/20/schema-compare-in-sqlpackage-and-the-data-tier-application-framework-dacfx/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update an SSDT project from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948453/how-to-update-an-ssdt-project-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the command line tools do not support updating a database project. Only the GUI schema compare mechanism supports this.